# Android Kotlin instrumentation test not recognized as instrumentation test

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to write a kotlin instrumentation test in my Android project. it's pretty basic for the moment:

```
class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    fun aTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

When I run it, it says that `no tests were found`. But when I run the Java version of this class I'm prompted to choose the device on which I want to run the test (meaning that AS recognizes it as an instrumentation test).

The Java version looks like this:

```
public class AnyTest {

    @Test
    void aTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

If I then convert this Java class to Kotlin and re-run the test, I get the same `no tests were found`.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I have he exact same problem . Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It seems more people have his problem too... https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/empty-test-suite-if-running-a-kotlin-test/6712

Comment: @DavidStanete No i haven't

Comment: Hi @HusaynHakeem, did you resolved your issue? If so, please let us know how. Thanks in advance!